# Variable not working in simple Ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Can't seem to get the variable getID to work. I'm trying to change the html of the div. I know that the variable has the right value.

```
$('.cardid').change(function() {
    var getID = $(this).attr('value');

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "inc/change_thumbnail.php",
        data: "id="+getID,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#"+getID).html(data);
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert("error"); 
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? How do you know the variable has the right value, have you logged it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value of an input :

```
var getID = $(this).val();
```

As you're making a POST request, you should also use the data argument to let jQuery properly send the value :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "inc/change_thumbnail.php",
    data: {id:getID},
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $("#"+getID).html(data);
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert("error"); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe it's a checkbox input.

Comment: Thanks. It's a select option. For some reason thought it is not passing the data through correctly? The variable does not get passed in the url

Comment: You're making a POST request. You should probably use the data argument of $.ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Write data in $.ajax as **data: {id : getID},** instead of **data: "id="+getID,**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('[id="'+getID+'"]').html(data);
```

and yes you should pass it this way:

```
data:{id:getID}
```